# Error with micombine.cor with miceadds

Tags: r, pool, imputation, r-mice

I do not have a reproducible example here but I am hoping to see if the following error is diagnostic of an obvious problem.

Using miceadds, I am running correlations on data that has been imputed with MICE. I receive the following error when a continuous variable ("6") (-0.5 to 1.4) is added to the model.

```
  micombine.cor(imp, variables=c(3:4:5:6))
```

Above results in the following error

```
  Error in stats::cor(dat_ii, dat_jj, method = method, use = 
  "pairwise.complete.obs") : 
  'y' must be numeric
  In addition: Warning messages:
  1: In 3:4:5 : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
  2: In 3:4:5:6 :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: Id guess it might be due to `3:4:5:6` which is not proper R syntax. Try it on its own in the r terminal. Try using either or `3:6`, `c(3:5, 6)`, or some other variant.  Also make sure all variables are numeric, as `'y' must be numeric` would suggest otherwise (but that may be a symptom of the incorrect syntax)

Comment: 3:4:5 does work and it is any combination involving 6 (e.g., 3:6) that produces the error. I did wonder about the numeric error--all 3-6 are numeric (and appears as numeric within the long format MI) but "is.numeric" for the MIDS object says it is neither numeric nor factor. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think `3:4:5` is working by luck rather than default. f you type `3:4:5` in the terminal you will get a warning. Do the examples in `micombine.cor` specify the `variables` using the more standard (what I'd call correct) approach or like you have done? As for other suggestions, really need some sort of reproducible example